# Huawei E170 doesn't work with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, usb, modem, hsdpa

I've got a "Huawei E170" (HSDPA broadband modem USB stick) with a driver CD for Windows XP & Vista, but now I got a netbook with Windows 7, and the driver installer won't run.

I've called the telecom, but they just offered to sell me a new stick :-(

Is there really no Win7 driver available for the E170 stick? Or can I trick it into installing anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself `:-)`

The problem was that the installer said it doesn't run on Windows 7; it requires Windows XP or Vista. The solution is to use Windows 7's `compatibility mode` to make the installer believe it is running on WinXP!

Instead of double-clicking the installer, I right-clicked, selected `Properties` then `Compatibility`, then ticked the box to run as Windows XP and also ticked the box to run as administrator, then `OK` and double-click the installer like normal.

Then the installer completes just fine, and after a reboot and some waiting, the modem is detected and actually works! I know for sure because I've turned off WLAN and I'm reporting this via the HSPDA connection.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](http://www.mobilebroadbandrocks.com/device/huawei-e170-e172) Vodafone says [this](http://www.business.vodafone.com/site/bus/public/enuk/support/10_productsupport/laptop_connectivity/40_software/software/faq/p_faq401.jsp) about windows 7.

The E170 isn't explictly listed, but if it's like the E172 it should work, but it may just be Vodafone who's willing to support Windows 7 and not your telecom.

If all else fails, sell the stick to a Linux user and buy another stick.

Comment: So you mean this E170 stick would actually work under Linux? That would be a great argument for installing Linux on the Netbook :-)

Comment: It looks like it's supported out of the box (there might be some firmware).  A LiveCD would be your best bet.