# Huawei E170 on Linux?

Tags: usb, modem, ubuntu-9.10, hsdpa

Related to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/124435/huawei-e170-doesnt-work-with-windows-7), I need to know if the specific combination of Ubuntu 9.10 + the Huawei E170 (HSDPA broadband modem USB stick) will work? Bonus points for a link to a webpage that decsribes exactly how it is done!

Specifically, I'm in Austria and the telco is A1, but I hope that the setup would be the same regardless of location/provider. Also, I'm looking for a solution where the user (my wife!!) doesn't need to enter any `sudo` commands to get this working. Can I dream of true plug-and-play?

I have found [these](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=609534) [two](http://www.linux.ie/articles/tutorials/threeirelandUSBmodem.php) pages that seem horribly complicated to a Linux noob. Is there a simpler way, or do I really need to dive into that?

Your input is much appreciated! If I can get confirmation that it's supported, then I'd switch to Ubuntu Netbook Remix, because I'm already running Ubuntu on the main pc at home and I'd like to keep things simple.

Comment: Update: This issue has kind of died because I couldn't fully switch to Ubuntu, and having both OS'es was too much trouble. I'm back on Windows, so I won't be able to really verify any of the given answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those two links both point to articles written nearly 3 years ago and a lot of improvements have been made since then. The latest versions of Ubuntu make using the Huawei modems very simple. Much less hassle than using the same modems on Windows, however SMS options are not provided. You can try Ubuntu 9.10 without making changes to your computer by booting the the Desktop version 'live' off CD or USB stick. The USB stick version allows settings to be saved and is faster too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to just add the usb modem as a "normal" network device? [This](http://www.mathewpacker.com/how-to-installing-a-3g-usb-modem-on-eeepc/) blog post explains how to do it on eeepc (which is running Xandros), but I would guess ubuntu should be able to do something similar.

Comment: No, haven't tried that yet because I haven't installed Linux yet, still running original Win7. But the link looks *very* promising!! I'll have to check it out soon. I guess I can try the steps on my Ubuntu desktop pc, it should be the same.